# Regex Substitution from the Selected Regex Group

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, regex-group

I have the following string

> I only work between September 12 -14 at this place. I will be back
>   between May 10-15 next year.

Using the following regex, I am able to capture the required part of strings i.e. the Month following by the dates

> (\w+\s?)(\d{1,2}\s?)-(\d{1,2})

This regex returns 2 full matches

Match 1

- **Full Match**: September 12 -14
- **Group 1**: September
- **Group 2**: 12
- **Group 3**: 14

Match 2

- **Full Match**: May 10-15
- **Group 1**: May
- **Group 2**: 10
- **Group 3**: 15

What I want is to insert Group 1 before Group 3 using regex substitution. 
Although there are other ways I can think of doing this, I couldn't find a way to do it using regex substitution.

I plan to use it in python.

The desired output should look something like this.

> I only work between September 12 -September 14 at this place. I will be back
>   between May 10-May 15 next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match

```
(\w+) ?(\d{1,2} ?-)(\d{1,2})
```

and replace with the first group, the second group, the first group again (to insert the month), and then the third group:

```
\1 \2\1 \3
```

https://regex101.com/r/Zcqsr2/1

```
import re
str = 'I only work between September 12 -14 at this place. I will be back between May 10-15 next year.'
print(re.sub(r'(\w+) ?(\d{1,2} ?-)(\d{1,2})', r'\1 \2\1 \3', str))
```